# Does Retrofit cache the authorization requests

Tags: android, caching, authorization, retrofit

I'm trying to implement Retrofit in my app, and everything it's working just fine, except that the requests are not cached.

So I have:

```
@GET("/mobile/api.php")
public void getPromos(
       @QueryMap Map<String, String> options, 
       Callback<ResultPromotions> callBack);
```

.....

```
 requestFacade.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationValue);
 requestFacade.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=600");
```

....

```
 RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
```

So my question is: dose retrofit cache the authorization requests? Or there is no way to cache this type of requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit itself does absolutely no caching.

If you want caching, it will either have to be at the application layer above Retrofit which knows about your domain and how to cache things in it or it needs to be at the HTTP client layer below Retrofit which knows the semantics of HTTP.

[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp) is an HTTP client also by Square which supports the semantics of caching server responses. If the response from the server has the `Cache-Control` header, for example, it will be cached so that subsequent requests for the same resource pull from the cache.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was on the response headers. There was an "no-cache" header.. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Hey Jake, I am facing caching issue with retrofit. Here is my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140400/retrofit-is-returning-cached-response). Please have a look.