# Retrofit is returning cached response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit in an Android application. When I hit an API with token to get user information it gives cached(previous) response. Whenever I logged out and log in again API gives previous user detail, I tested API in Postman it works fine there.

I have tried some solutions I searched but nothing is working.

**Response header that I am getting is**

> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Server: Kestrel
>   Date: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 09:35:26 GMT

Below is `ApiClient` class

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/api/";
private static Retrofit authRetrofit = null;
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

 public static Retrofit getAuthorizeClient(final String token) {

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .addHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    //.cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.cache(null).build();

    if (authRetrofit == null) {
        authRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client).build();
    }
    return authRetrofit;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the response from the API including (http) headers? Usually retrofit respects the cache information from the http headers.

Comment: I'm response it gives JSON object that has two fields user name and email but it's previous user's detail that has logged in

Comment: And the http headers?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am getting this in response header

`Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Date: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 09:35:26 GMT`

Comment: So the API did not send cache control headers?

Comment: Yes, there is no cache control headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `httpClient` interceptor, try adding cache control header:

```
 .addHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache");
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed you are on `Retrofit2`

```
original.newBuilder().header("Cache-control", "no-cache");
```

Alternatively try adding it as an annotation to your API method:

```
@Headers("Cache-control: no-cache")
Response callApi();
```

According to [Docs.](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)

**EDIT 2**

Okay I suspect it's because of your `if` condition, your `authRetrofit` wouldn't be updated if condition failed. Try removing it

`if (authRetrofit == null)`

Help this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jiyeh, You can check my code I have already tried this, it does not work, I have commented that line.

Comment: @AshishTiwari I don't see that directive in your code, He said ``no-cache``, your tried ``no-store``

Comment: I tried it yesterday! wait I am trying again.
I have specified it in two ways
1- `.cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder().noCache().build())`
2-  ` .addHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache");`

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: if remove the `if (authRetrofit == null)` condition every time i will get new instance of retrofit client. I am using it in multiple places.

Comment: I set retrofit client to null when logging out. its working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Post request instead, I've faced the same problem, rectified by changing my GET method to post and send one random string as a Field.