# Android phone caches network response

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I experienced a strange issue in my Android app where one of the phone seems to cache the network calls. The app seems to return the same response irrespective of which user I try to login with.

When I try to inspect the request I can see the old response being received. But when I try to replay the request as is in a curl or using postman I get an updated response. I am using retrofit to make API calls. This behaviour is encountered only on a specific device (Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime). Not sharing code here since it doesn't look like a issue in the code since this is working on other devices.

Is there a possibility that android SDK (modified) itself might be caching the network calls to save device resources?

Comment: it might be because of the server caching of galaxy j7 or other device for using low data

Comment: If you are calling HTTP API with 'GET' method, then it might be possible that API response has cache control header (something like: Cache-Control: max-age=3600). Solution is if backend team has kept it purposefully, you can append timestamp in API URL like http://test.com?t=[current timestamp]

Comment: @AjayKS Is it possible that I can get rid of this caching?

Comment: @VIjayJ There is nothing like `Cache-Control` that we are using in the request.

Comment: Cache-Control is added in API response headers. Check your API response headers

Comment: @VIjayJ I don't see anything like that being coming in the response.

Comment: That was one of the possible cause, For further investigation, please check community question that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140400/retrofit-is-returning-cached-response